# Suppress a logger by name

Tags: python

I have some modules each implementing a class where each class creates its own logger with

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and the module uses this with  `self.logger.info()`, `self.logger.debug()` and so on.

Now I want to suppress the log messages from one specific class. But the class invokes the logger functions. The Python logging system allows to set the log level with

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

But that does not allow to specify the logger name. Would it be possible to create a dummy logger and use in the class to suppress? Are there other means to control the log output by the logger name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get logger of third party library and set different (less verbose) level on it:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger('third.party.library')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Since `__name__` expands to fully qualified module name and loggers are hierarchical (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects)) you need only set level on `getLogger('third')` to cover all child modules under `third`.